# how to construct free resolution of the $ℤ_{4} $ module $ℤ_{2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

can somebody please explain how to construct free resolution of the $ℤ_{4} $ module $ℤ_{2}$??

Comment: Is $\Bbb Z_4$ a $\Bbb Z_2$-module?

Comment: What's wrong with the usual method? 1) Set $M=$ the module you want to resolve. 2) Write $M$ as a quotient of a free module. 3) Identify the kernel $N$ of the quotient map you got in step 2. 4) If $N=0$ stop, you are done. Otherwise, set $M=N$ and go back to step 2.

Answer (score 2):

A free resolution is given by
$$
\dots \xrightarrow 2 \mathbb Z /4\xrightarrow 2 \mathbb Z/4\xrightarrow 2 \mathbb Z/4 \rightarrow \mathbb Z/2,
$$
where the last map is enlargement of cosets and, by a standard abuse of notation, $2$ denotes the map $\bar 1\mapsto \bar 2$ (where bar denotes residue class). See the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375156/if-m-divides-n-find-a-free-resolution-of-mathbbz-m-as-a-mathbbz-n?rq=1).